# After Google Analytics creates a project and associates it with firebase, why is there no data view problem?

Tags: google-analytics

When I create the Google analytical project, click to associate with firebase, display the data to be tracked, and view the data view, I find that there is no menu operation associated with the data view, and there is no default data view creation. This is a question to ask for leave.

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhT8O.png     This is my management interface, but there is no data view available.